# Azure Postgresql migartion from single server v11 to flexible server v14 - permission denied

Tags: postgresql, azure, database-migration

I am getting this error while performing migration between postgresql single server and flexible server:

```
Data migration could not be started for one or more of the DBSets. Error details: PGv2RestoreError: PG Restore failed for database 'postgres' with exit code '1' and error message 'error: could not execute query: ERROR: permission denied to create "pg_catalog.hypopg_list_indexes"'.
```

Which quite clearly states that user which is performing migration dosen't have right to perform some operations with creating extensio in pg_catalog. The problem is that in Azure i CAN NOT have superuser, so it seems like there is no way to perform this operation. Every step is done using azure platform and in compilance with guides below.
Also it looks like problem lies with hypopg extension, which is enabled on both databases.

guides:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/migrate/how-to-migrate-single-to-flexible-portal
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/migrate/concepts-single-to-flexible
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/migrate/concepts-single-to-flexible#migration-prerequisites

Answer (score 1):

Please drop the hypopg extension on the source server before migration (for each DB the extension was created in): and give it a try.
DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS hypopg;
If needed, it could then be recreated after migration on the source:
CREATE EXTENSION hypopg;

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the HypoPG extension seems to have been installed in the `pg_catalog` schema.  Move it to a different schema on the old database:

```
ALTER EXTENSION hypopg SET SCHEMA public;
```

Comment: SQL Error [0A000]: ERROR: cannot remove dependency on schema pg_catalog because it is a system object

Comment: Then try to drop the extension and create it again in a normal schema. It may well be that Microsoft hacked up PostgreSQL in this area, so that it behaves different from normal PostgreSQL. In that case, you will have to ask Microsoft.